# Переменная окружения в ant

Tags: ant, gwt, java

Столкнулся с проблемой, в ант скрипте не подцепить переменную окружения, ОС Windows, но подразумевается, что билдовый скрипт кросс-платформенный. Пишут так:

```
<property name="gwt.sdk" location="${GWT_PATH}" />
```

При этом GWT_PATH выставлен как D:/gwt-2.0.3. В результате я получаю путь до библиотек

```
path/to/current/dir/GWT_PATH/gwt-user.jar
```

Где посмотреть, чтоб поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, нужно задавать адрес немного по-другому:

```
<property name="gwt.sdk" value="${GWT_PATH}" />
```

Comment: Глупая ошибка была :(

Comment: Да ничего, бывает